# Pylance has two same resolution results

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylance

I am coding python script using vscode
with extensions of Python and Pylance. I met a problem as the picture below

[image]

there are two same resolution results at the same time,
and not only for the import;
any other place like resolving variables, modules and functions,
there are always two same results.

If forbidding Pylance, there will be no resolution.
So I wonder how to fix this problem.

Comment: FWIW, I'm not seeing this in VSCode using Jedi.

Comment: What version is your jupyter extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade the **Jupyter** extension to the pre-release version.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution! It works for me. And I found that this double-resolution appears once after I open a notebook. Is this due to the bug of the current version of jupyter?